# Is there something like .NET's data annotations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .net, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I was looking for something similar to .net's data annotations in rails, something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826304/Basic-Introduction-to-Data-Annotation-in-NET-Frame).

What I want to achieve by this is: I have some fields (they could be nil also) for which I want to check the length and if the length exceeds I want to display an error message.

I want to club all the error messages related to, say all blog posts (which again have many separate fields) and then display them at once.

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses ActiveRecord validations.  In many cases the default validations are easy to set up.  But if you want/or need customized validations that can all be done as well.   Read the documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

In your case this type of validation is built in to rails so it's simple as adding 1 line to your model:

```
class MyModel
  validates :my_field_name, length: { maximum: 3 }, allow_blank: true
end
```

This will validate the maximum length of your field.  You can also customize the validation error message:

```
class MyModel
  validates :name, presence: {message: "Title can't be blank." }, uniqueness: {message: "Title already exists."}, length: { maximum: 5, message: "Must be less than 5 characters"}
end
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried the above snippet it didn't work but this works:



validates :name, 
          :presence => {:message => "Title can't be blank." },
          :uniqueness => {:message => "Title already exists."},
          :length => { :maximum => 5, :message => "Must be less than 5 characters"}

Comment: I had to add messages to each validations

Comment: You should only need to do that if you need to override the standard rails error messages, otherwise the first version I gave should work.  I updated answer also with newer ruby syntax with custom messages.